# Make datatable column data to hyperlink with parameters

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I am using datatable on dashboard of my application, now i want to make one of my column result as hyperlink. when i click that text it should open a modal

here is code

```
> $dataTable = $('#orders-table').DataTable({
>                 processing: true,
>                 serverSide: true,
>                 ajax: '{!! route('orders.data',['status' => implode("|",$status), 'naqel_status' => implode("|",$naqel_status),
> 'assigned_user' => implode("|",$assigned_user)]) !!}',
>                 lengthMenu: [20, 50, 75, 100],
>                 order: [ 0, 'desc' ],
>                 columns: [
>                     {data: 'order_id', name: 'order_id'},
>                     {data: 'order_reference',
>                         "render":function(data){
>                             data = '<a onclick="openFormModal(this)" data-route="{{ route('orders.detail', ['order' => $data->order_id])
> }}">' + data + '</a>';
>                             return data;
>                         }
>                     },
>                 ],
>             });
```

> i want to make order reference as hyperlink but what i actually facing
>   problem is i dont know how to pass order id here with this route.
>   Order id is avaliable in $data but i can't access here.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use laravel routes. render of datatable is executed client side ... you should place the URL manually ... supposing you route is something like `/orders/detail/{id}` then your code should be

```
"render": function(data){
    var cell = '<a onclick="openFormModal(this)" data-route="/orders/detail/' + data.order_id + '">' + data.order_reference + '</a>';
    return cell;
}
```